# How to handle Exception in Reflection(method.invoke) in C# with try catch

Tags: c#

when exception is throwing from invoked method it's unable to catch and throw the exception.

```
`try
{
     Type type = Type.GetType("abc");
     Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
     MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("xyz");
     object[] parameters = { new object[] { Json } };
     response = (methodInfo.Invoke(obj, parameters));
}
catch
{
     throw;
}
`
```

Comment: Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your code anyway. try to continue execution of code.
In the Debug/Exceptions menu, remove all checks. It should work.

```
try
{
     Type type = Type.GetType("abc");
     Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
     MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("xyz");
     object[] parameters = { new object[] { Json } };
     response = (methodInfo.Invoke(obj, parameters));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception thrown from a method call to Invoke() using reflection is a wrapping exception instance of System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException. The actual exception you're after will be in the InnerException. And don't forget to allow exceptions being thrown in visual studio using **Debug-> Exception->**

```
try
{
 Type type = Type.GetType("abc");
 Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
 MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("xyz");
 object[] parameters = { new object[] { Json } };
 response = (methodInfo.Invoke(obj, parameters));
}
catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
{
    ex = ex.InnerException; // ex now stores the original exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the `response.Exception?.InnerException`

```
try
{
    Type type = Type.GetType("abc");
    Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("xyz");
    object[] parameters = { new object[] { Json } };
    response = (methodInfo.Invoke(obj, parameters));
 
    if(response != null && response.Exception?.InnerException is Exception){
        //this is an exception from reflection
        throw response.Exception?.InnerException;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex){
    throw;
}
```